# ASP.NET MVC passing strongly typed data to master page

Tags: asp.net-mvc

### Duplicate

> [Passing data to Master Page in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78548/passing-data-to-master-page-in-asp-net-mvc)
>
> [Should an ASP.NET masterpage get its data from the view ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/467855/should-an-asp-net-masterpage-get-its-data-from-the-view)

I have been following this method for passing common data to the site.master. However, this does require specific casting of the ViewData and I don't like using string identifiers everywhere. Is this the best way to do it or is there another way?

http://www.asp.net/learn/MVC/tutorial-13-cs.aspx

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could create a base class that all your models inherit from:

```
class MasterModel {
     // common info, used in master page.
}

class Page1Model : MasterModel {
     // page 1 model
}
```

Then your master page would inherit from `ViewMasterPage<MasterModel>` and your `Page1.aspx` would inherit from `ViewPage<Page1Model>` and set `Site.master` as its master page.

Comment: Thanks, simple explanation! (saw this before but had trouble understanding it)

Answer (score 2):

As I struggled a bit, here is my contribution :

```
class ModelBase {
     // common info, used in master page.
}

class Page1Model : ModelBase {
     // page 1 model
}

public class ControllerBase : Controller
{
    protected override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        var model = ViewData.Model as ModelBase;

        // set common data here

        base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is also how I do it. Furthermore, you could throw an exception if model is not an instance of ModelBase, thereby ensuring that only valid models are passed to the view.